# What was Vyshinsky's position about extrajudical repressions in the USSR?

Tags: soviet-union

Vyshinsky was the prosecutor-general of the USSR who is mosly known for his participation in the Moscow show trials of the 1930s.

But what was his position regarding the extrajudical repressions?

Comment: In the usual sense, the question is moot, because he, as every other Soviet official, could have *no* personal position except for that given by the party line at the moment. Or did you mean to ask what Vyshinsky the man, as distinct from Vyshinsky the official, thought about it in the depth of his heart? That'd more of a question for speculative psychology than for history.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - presumably there could have been some personal correspondence of his.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg i heard that in some party meeting in 1937 he was critical of the proposed repressions and called for uniform application of law.

Comment: @Anixx: maybe he was piling on Ezhov as part of the latter's downfall.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg it was before the purges started. Of course, after the repressions were criticized everybody would say the same. May be I am wrong and he in fact was critical in 1936 rather than 1937.

Comment: Well, we are descending into idle guesswork here. If you can find the relevant quote and date, we can discuss it.

Comment: As a candidate member of the 19th Presidium (the then name for the politbureau), it is possible that he expressed an opinion in a Presidium meeting.  However, the minutes of presidium meetings I've read from 1956 show extremely guarded positions amongst presidium members.